# onblur event not fired every time

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The `onblur` event is not always firing.

It's not very predictable. I included a small program that you can run to replicate the problem. You need to click inside the iframe and see if in the consol there's `asti`. If it's there, everything is alright with the world. Sometimes, however, the `onblur` doesn't fire and nothing is printed. The failure frequency is about 5%.

Why does the `onblur` event not always fire?

```
<html>
  <head>  
    <title> INDEX </title>
  </head>
  <body >
    <h1> TABARNAC </h1>
    <p>chikanuti</p>
    <iframe src=""></iframe>
  </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
    document.activeElement.blur();
    window.focus();
    body.onblur=function(){
        console.log("asti");
    };
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: nono, i mean that the user clicks inside the iframe

Comment: It’s not easy to reproduce this… it’s working perfectly fine for me, every time. Apart from that: why not use `document.body` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`?

Comment: Using `window.onblur` might be more accurate: http://jsfiddle.net/2bqf21e7/

Comment: There is some inconsistent behavior across browsers when it comes to this. In IE it worked sometimes, in Chrome sometimes, in Firefox I couldn't get it to work at all. I was doing something similar and spent days trying to debug it. Instead, I ended up adding an onfocus for the iframe and put my code there. It worked 100% consistently for me.

Answer (score 0):

The `onblur` event fires when you leave an element (the element loses focus). So, 
when you click the `iframe`, the `body` loses focus and the event fires. If you click the out of the `iframe`, and then click the `iframe` again, the event will fire again.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/42tbd4fb/